# Patroni Cluster initializing with scram-sha 256

Tags: postgresql, installation, patroni

When I am trying to install patroni , I can initialize database with md5 , all the cluster is working well. .

But when i tried to install patroni with initializing scram-sha 256 . It is not starting also status stay

"replica" for all database instancess in cluster. Also on patroni logs i can see this error ""postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM verifier" . What is the solution for this ?

Info : password_encryption is scram-sha 256
All hba.conf entries are scram-sha 256.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the configuration parameter `password_encryption` to `scram-sha-256` *before* setting a password for the user PostgreSQL.

If you don't know how to do that initially, use `trust` authentication for the setup and modify that later, when you have set the SCRAM password.

Comment: On my patroni yml ; on parameters; password_encryption : "scram-sha-256" on pg_hba:

local all postgres scram-sha-256
host database user xxxx scram-sha-256
but when initialize the db i got a error :

""postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM verifier".

It is easy to do trust and continue . I don't want to do it . I want to start patroni with scram-sha-256 . But I couldn't find the way.

Comment: Did you set a password for the user?

Comment: I am setting password in yml file like     superuser:
      username: postgres
      password: STRONGPASSWORD  , Am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: Try the following experiment: use trust authentication and do everything else like you are doing it now. Then connect to the database and look at the password in `pg_authid`. Is there one? Is it MD5 hashed or SCRAM hashed? That should give you important information.

Comment: It is hashed as SCRAM Laurenz,Thanks